# Java Script, get info from ever users specific profile feild from wordpress and add to list

Tags: java, javascript, wordpress

im trying to figure out how to get javascript to grab each users "twitchname" field from their profile, and have it add it to the list of streamers.

Currently, we have to type in everyone's channel name in the JS code Below: console_purgatory being the name, but we have added a profile field where they add it to their profile, we just want to get that field for every user and add it to here.

```
var members = ['console_purgatory'];
```

This is the PHP thats currently able to display the users twitch name.

```
<?php echo xprofile_get_field_data( 'TWITCH TV Url', $current_user->ID ); ?>
```

Im very new to JS so if you need more info please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways.

#### First

You can place PHP code inline in your JavaScript in **.php** files. THis is not very nice looking mixture of code but it works.

```
<script>
var members = ['console_purgatory'];
var id = <?php echo xprofile_get_field_data( 'TWITCH TV Url', $current_user->ID ); ?>
</script>
```

#### Second

You can use ajax requests to separate services to obtain ID.

**service.php** contains

```
<?php 
echo xprofile_get_field_data( 'TWITCH TV Url', $current_user->ID );
```

**script.js** - this uses jQuery.ajax() function ([more here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/))

```
var members = ['console_purgatory'];
var id = undefined;
$.ajax({
  url: "service.php",
  data: data,
  async: false,
  success: function( data ) {
    id = data;
  }
});
console.log(id); // <-- id is equal to 'data' which is equal to echo in service.php
```

Comment: I not sure im following, the "var members = ['']" is where the channel names are listed so in it should end up like "var members = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4']"

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question but the methog of getting PHP variable in JavaScript is like above. Perhaps you're looking for something more like `var members = ['<?php echo xprofile_get_field_data( 'TWITCH TV Url', $current_user->ID ); ?>'];`?

Comment: I see, well i tried that and it didn't work, but yet basically for example, "<?php echo xprofile_get_field_data( 'TWITCH TV Username', $current_user->ID  ); ?>" will display the users twitch tv name.

Comment: This is an example of what I'm trying to describe: http://codepad.viper-7.com/kMGGEC. If this doesn't help or clarify anything, then I'm out of ideas.